# Transforming a simple loop to list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why the first "titles" list doesnt work but the second works ? how do i make the first one work ?
Thank you!

```py
highlighted_poems = "Afterimages:Audre Lorde:1997,  The Shadow:William Carlos Williams:1915, Ecstasy:Gabriela Mistral:1925,   Georgia Dusk:Jean Toomer:1923,   Parting Before Daybreak:An Qi:2014, The Untold Want:Walt Whitman:1871, Mr. Grumpledump's Song:Shel Silverstein:2004, Angel Sound Mexico City:Carmen Boullosa:2013, In Love:Kamala Suraiyya:1965, Dream Variations:Langston Hughes:1994, Dreamwood:Adrienne Rich:1987"

highlighted_poems_list = highlighted_poems.split(',')

highlighted_poems_stripped = [line.strip() for line in highlighted_poems_list]

highlighted_poems_details = [line.split(':') for line in highlighted_poems_stripped]
print(highlighted_poems_details)

print()
print()
print()
print(highlighted_poems_details[1][1])

titles = [titles.append(title[0]) for title[0] in highlighted_poems_details]
#poets = [poet[1].append() for poet in highlighted_poems_details]
#dates = [date[2].append() for date in highlighted_poems_details]

for title in highlighted_poems_details:
  titles.append(title[0])
print(titles)
```

Comment: remove `append` --> `titles = [title[0] for title in highlighted_poems_details]
`

Answer (score 2):

Correct:

```
titles = [title[0] for title in highlighted_poems_details]
```

You are not appending anything to list of comprehension, you are defining it.

Answer (score 1):

When working with list comprehension, you have to first read the expression after the `for` and then the first part:

```
titles = [title[0] for title in highlighted_poems_details]
          ^------^     ^--------------------------------^
              |                            |
       the information              iteration over 
       you want to add              your data
       to your new list
```

So you could read it like this: `for every title in the poem details, add title[0] to the list`

Answer (score 0):

Or use:

```
from operator import itemgetter
titles = list(map(itemgetter(0), highlighted_poems_details))
```

Answer (score 0):

why it does not work? because you are using undefined variable `title` while using `title[0]`, see marked below

```
titles = [titles.append(title[0]) for title[0] in highlighted_poems_details]
------------------------^^^^^^^-------^^^^^^^------------------------------
```

You can use, as suggested by Relandom

```
titles = [title[0] for title in highlighted_poems_details]
```